# AngularJS $watch callback fires but no changes in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, data-synchronization

Am using rest api to get the users from a sharepoint group and if the current user present in that particular group the form (the view) must have some extra options and buttons visible. So am using $watch to detect the changes in the variable assigned to rest api return value and inside the $watch callback am defining the changes in the view. Now when Rest api returns $watch function fires but the view is still not updated.

If I execute,

```
angular.element('[ng-controller=controllerName]').scope().$apply();
```

in console, then my form loads fine.

Comment: Use scope.$apply in the watch...

Comment: I think the page renders before the $watch callback.

Comment: try $apply() inside a setTimeOut. (be-careful with this inside setTimeOut is not the this outside it.)

Comment: Please post more code.  It's hard to diagnose exactly what is going wrong with what you have shown so far.  Are you using `$http`?  Where, when, and how are you attaching your `$watch`?  An [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help.

Comment: Am using $q of angularjs for asynchronous issues. But the problem is the rest call and checking the user by if condition happens at the same time on page load. So sometimes even before promise is resolved, the correct If condition becomes false and it goes to else condition and as per this else condition the page renders! So I used $watch for variable change, and it fires, so the correct if condition executes, but the page renders before the $watch callback and its empty. When I press F12 and executes $apply in console the page loads fine. Even the $apply inside $watch callback is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular's $http service for making your requests, it will handle updating the view automatically. If you're making your requests without it, Angular needs to be told that the data has changed.

While you *can* use a watch, it's not the best way to accomplish this. I recommend using $http. If you cannot, simply call $timeout() in your response function.

Also, regarding this:
`angular.element('[ng-controller=controllerName]').scope().$apply();`

If you're calling this within your controller, you can simply call scope.$apply(), no need for accessing the DOM. This line implies issues with your overall approach though.

Comment: Am using $q of angularjs for asynchronous issues. But the problem is the rest call and checking the user by if condition happens at the same time on page load. So sometimes even before promise is resolved, the correct If condition becomes false and it goes to else condition and as per this else condition the page renders! So I used $watch for variable change, and it fires, so the correct if condition executes, but the page renders before the $watch callback and its empty. When I press F12 and executes $apply in console the page loads fine. Even the $apply inside $watch callback is not working.